# import bsh.This; statement in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, when I did with my coding part, I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to remove unused import statements.

This works fine. But sometimes it automatically adds one line as below.

```
import bsh.This;
```

And this line did not recognize as compile error in Eclipse.

Eclipse version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

JDK version: 8

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Does your program have anything to do with BeanShell?

Comment: No. Nothing is there related to BeanShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for `import bsh.This;` after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Please see the following code and its documentation:

```
/**
* @author Brijesh
* @param param1
* @param param2
* @see **This** method is used for some purpose
*/
public void someLogicHere(Object param1, Object param2) {

}
```

As you can see, there is one keyword **This** in see section.
Eclipse is trying to import this from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes it automatically adds one line as below.

You probably have a stray `This` (note the capital T there) in your program which isn't linked to a type so causes a compilation error - you may have meant to write the Java keyword `this` (lower case t) instead.

However, Eclipse doesn't know that, as far as it's concerned `This` is just another type that you may want to import. So it'll search for available imports and insert the relevant one it finds, which happens to be `bsh.This` in this case.

You should almost certainly just remove this, and fix any incorrect references to `This` (with a capital `T`) in your class.